# Best way to store retrieved contacts in our own android app?

Tags: android

I tried using hashmap, but some suggested that hash map is not reliable to store contacts. And I cannot perform retrieve operation every time I run the app. So suggest me any useful way to store contacts. If possible provide me the link, so that it helps me for further reference.

Comment: There is a standard way to do it in Android. ContentProviders and ContentResolver . Now go and dive in it

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have retrieved the contacts well and good,But I need to store it and display it in autocompletetextview.

Comment: If you want to store the data beyond the scope of your activity lifecycle or even Application lifecycle  then don't go with HashMap. It will not be persistent . Create a SQLite DB or if number or entries are small then you can use SharedPreferences . Then you can retrieve those values.

Answer (score 0):

This is code for retrieve contacts from phone

```
 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

  while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

   String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY));

   String phonenumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

 }
```

Comment: From question: *cannot perform retrieve operation every time*. Answer: *code for retrieve*. Oh boy, you need another coffee...